# System Volume Information: Access Denied

Tags: c++, windows

I have written a program that can search a physical device at the sector level, from start to finish.  Now I want to create a routine that will deal only with logical files.

Therefore, I need to recursively list all directories and files on an NTFS volume (or FAT32) using native C++.  The problem I am running into is an "access denied" error whenever I encounter a Windows System folder.

```
C:\System Volume Information and
C:\Users
```

are just two examples of these folders.

I am NOT looking to "skip over" these directories.  On the contrary, they are most important to the project at hand.

I have tried a variety of options that have been offered up in C++ forums etc. and all of them seem to either fail (access denied) or the quick answer is to "skip over" them.

At this point, I am wondering if I need to somehow lookup the physical sector for these folders and systematically trace through the extents at the physical sector level for each?

Looking for some help here and I would appreciate any ideas.  Thank you!

NOTE:  I saw no point in posting any sample code only because I've tried way too many combinations (most of which could read directories etc.) but all of which failed to navigate System directories.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I recommend this, but since you're very determined, why don't you just temporarily change the security descriptors on those folders with [SetFileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so you can open a handle, then change them back again? That should work.

Comment: That's overkill.  It should be enough simply to enable SeBackupPrivilege.

Comment: @Luke: Have you actually tried doing that? I don't remember if I ever tried it, but I do remember that traversing those folders was very hard, and I'm not sure if that'll work.

Comment: FindFirstFile et al. honor the Backup/Restore privileges.  I just verified with a test program to be 100% sure.

Comment: Oh wow, okay. Cool, thanks for sharing!! I'll find that useful too! :)